# setup the local 0x-api. internal server error in Order Watcher

Tags: go-ethereum, 0x

I'm tring to deploy 0x-api locally, when I use the api `/orderbook/v1/order` to create an order, I got the 500 Internal Server Error, the error log is :

```
 req: {
      "id": "bbce499b-61f8-4efc-b502-537a61edd15d",
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/orderbook/v1/order",
      "query": {},
      "params": {},
      "headers": {
        "host": "localhost:3000",
        "user-agent": "python-requests/2.28.1",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "accept": "*/*",
        "connection": "keep-alive",
        "content-length": "824",
        "content-type": "application/json"
      },
      "remoteAddress": "::1",
      "remotePort": 57596,
      "body": {
        "maker": "0x5409ED021D9299bf6814279A6A1411A7e866A631",
        "taker": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "makerToken": "0xdD66C23e07b4D6925b6089b5Fe6fc9E62941aFE8",
        "takerToken": "0x4609e0ED27A8BAAc57b753D36a5D2971915588f9",
        "makerAmount": "100",
        "takerAmount": "100",
        "expiry": "1663148819",
        "salt": "1663062419",
        "feeRecipient": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "pool": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "takerTokenFeeAmount": "0",
        "sender": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "verifyingContract": "0x404C55a936f3006B13B020efAaf5771A600Ec04d",
        "chainId": "1337",
        "signature": {
          "signatureType": 3,
          "v": 27,
          "r": "0xd45a6d4b6c74a1eae430650482fc952439ed2dbf259aac70db41e2b1e851cde7",
          "s": "0x4ef46094dbe50c27f19a324937333c9d4207983c2f559ff640a4dc082f90447f"
        }
      }
    }
    res: {
      "statusCode": 400,
      "headers": {
        "x-powered-by": "Express",
        "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "content-length": "122",
        "etag": "W/\"7a-OGECS0cXJvjbNJvMI8PKQ8Rsezs\""
      },
      "statusMessage": "Bad Request"
    }
    responseTime: 35
[1663062420234] INFO  (40631 on ms-air.local): request errored
    req: {
      "id": "8a3a0da2-500e-4a77-902e-35eabab160d2",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/orderbook/v1/orders?page=1&perPage=20&makerToken=0xdD66C23e07b4D6925b6089b5Fe6fc9E62941aFE8&takerToken=0x4609e0ED27A8BAAc57b753D36a5D2971915588f9",
      "query": {
        "page": "1",
        "perPage": "20",
        "makerToken": "0xdD66C23e07b4D6925b6089b5Fe6fc9E62941aFE8",
        "takerToken": "0x4609e0ED27A8BAAc57b753D36a5D2971915588f9"
      },
      "params": {},
      "headers": {
        "host": "localhost:3000",
        "user-agent": "python-requests/2.28.1",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "accept": "*/*",
        "connection": "keep-alive"
      },
      "remoteAddress": "::1",
      "remotePort": 57597,
      "body": {}
    }
    res: {
      "statusCode": 500,
      "headers": {
        "x-powered-by": "Express",
        "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "content-length": "63",
        "etag": "W/\"3f-qRnjtdWN3Ghq2t2KkLT+Wpm7fgk\""
      },
      "statusMessage": "Internal Server Error"
    }
    err: {
      "type": "Error",
      "message": "failed with status code 500",
      "stack":
          Error: failed with status code 500
              at ServerResponse.onResFinished (/Users/shotamasuda/dev/shinonome/amaterasu/orderbook/0x-api/node_modules/pino-http/logger.js:77:38)
              at ServerResponse.emit (events.js:412:35)
              at ServerResponse.emit (domain.js:475:12)
              at onFinish (_http_outgoing.js:792:10)
              at callback (internal/streams/writable.js:513:21)
              at afterWrite (internal/streams/writable.js:466:5)
              at afterWriteTick (internal/streams/writable.js:453:10)
              at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
    }
    responseTime: 158
[1663062420353] INFO  (40631 on ms-air.local): request errored
    req: {
      "id": "d1d801d7-12bf-4499-8dde-4c2a32c506ac",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/orderbook/v1/orders",
      "query": {},
      "params": {},
      "headers": {
        "host": "localhost:3000",
        "user-agent": "python-requests/2.28.1",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "accept": "*/*",
        "connection": "keep-alive"
      },
      "remoteAddress": "::1",
      "remotePort": 57600,
      "body": {}
    }
    res: {
      "statusCode": 500,
      "headers": {
        "x-powered-by": "Express",
        "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "content-length": "63",
        "etag": "W/\"3f-qRnjtdWN3Ghq2t2KkLT+Wpm7fgk\""
      },
      "statusMessage": "Internal Server Error"
    }
    err: {
      "type": "Error",
      "message": "failed with status code 500",
      "stack":
          Error: failed with status code 500
              at ServerResponse.onResFinished (/Users/shotamasuda/dev/shinonome/amaterasu/orderbook/0x-api/node_modules/pino-http/logger.js:77:38)
              at ServerResponse.emit (events.js:412:35)
              at ServerResponse.emit (domain.js:475:12)
              at onFinish (_http_outgoing.js:792:10)
              at callback (internal/streams/writable.js:513:21)
              at afterWrite (internal/streams/writable.js:466:5)
              at afterWriteTick (internal/streams/writable.js:453:10)
              at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
    }
    responseTime: 50
```

It seems that the error has occurred in `order_watcher.ts` at this line.

https://github.com/0xProject/0x-api/blob/aed083530cda15e14f31bf9e7babe048a3c9031c/src/utils/order_watcher.ts#L16

And What's ORDER_WATCHER_URL?

Any help is appreciated.